# Defaultdict of a Class - Get index/key of current called instance inside a class

Tags: python

Yep! I know you cannot understand by the title. 
Take for example the below code.

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = []
        self.identify = None #for now?
    def getRoom(self):
        #here I need to implement so that, 
        # self.identify is current indent this class is called!
        return self.identify
room = defualtdict(Room)
print room['Train'].getRoom()
print room['Hospital'].getRoom()
```

Excepted output.

```
#>>Train
#>>Hospital
```

Any such feature supported in defaultdict, so that I can do that?
Once the class of room 'something' is called, inside the class, I need a code so that, self.room is 'something' which is called!

Comment: You will need to inherit from defaultdict, why don't you want to instantiate instances normally, why is a dict necessary?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: If you see the above code, you can easily catch why I need to use a Dict for that class!

Comment: I understand from your code why but there are much simpler ways to do it.

Comment: Actually Am creating a Heavy server, Which supports rooms for users in a large core. So, I cannot always adapt the usability of `__getitem__` That may have chances of reducing the performance.
And, This will be the simplest way of implementing :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default factory of [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (any callable) does not accept arguments.

> If [*default_factory*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory) is not *None*, it is called without arguments to
>   provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in
>   the dictionary for the key, and returned.

In other words, `defaultdict` does not pass any information to the `default_factory`.

Subclass `defaultdict` to customize the default [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__) hook to call the `default_factory` (`Room` class constructor) with missing key as a parameter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class mydefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = new = self.default_factory(key)
        return new
```

The constructor of `Room` will then look like

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, identity):
        self.numbers = []
        self.identify = identity
```

You'll need to use `mydefaultdict` instead of `defaultdict` from now on. Example:

```
room = mydefaultdict(Room)
print(room['Train'].getRoom()) # Train 
print(room['Hospital'].getRoom()) # Hospital
```

While this works, I suggest you to re-think the way you store/access data.